# My API call works with postman but not with curl as it is not able to read a query parameter

Tags: api, rest, curl, postman

I am consuming a REST API (POST) which is something like:

`https://my.server.com/fooApp/rest/agent/<foo_id>/binaries?type=xxx&platform=LINUX`

This API as you can see has 2 query parameters and also requires certain json body to be sent along with the request. The request also requires two headers - content-type and a customized authentication token header. When I run this request via Postman, it works flawlessly however when I run this with curl, my server returns an error, "*Required String parameter &#39;platform&#39; is not present*" (Only posted the excerpt and omitted the other common stuff)

Following is how I am trying to consume the API with curl:

`curl -d @myRequestBody.json -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Session-token: MyAuthToken' https://my.server.com/fooApp/rest/agent/<foo_id>/binaries?type=xxx&platform=LINUX`

What am I missing? I am calling using curl directly from my Ubuntu shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens if you also surround the url with apostrophes?

```
curl -d @myRequestBody.json -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Session-token: MyAuthToken' 'https://my.server.com/fooApp/rest/agent/<foo_id>/binaries?type=xxx&platform=LINUX'
```

The shell probably sees the ampersand (&) and thinks that's the end of the command.

Comment: Worked perfectly @johan-nordlinder! And you are probably right about the & too. Just to validate your finding, I decided to change the sequence of query parameters and the error changed to other parameter (type) since that went after the ampersand! Thank you!